# ¿Se entiende en Hispanoamérica la expresión "no enterarse ni del nodo"?

Tags: expresiones, españa, hispanoamérica

En España hay una expresión

> No enterarse ni del nodo

que viene a significar "no enterarse de nada", "no enterarse ni de lo más básico" o "no enterarse de algo que está muy clarito".

A pesar de las diferentes acepciones de [nodo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QZ0uuUk%7CQZ2HrGw), entiendo que esta expresión se refiere concretamente al "No-Do"

> *De No-Do®, marca reg., acrón. de Noticiarios y Documentales.*
>
> 1. m. En las salas de cine de España entre 1943 y 1981, cortometraje documental que se exhibía antes de la proyección de las películas.

el No-Do era, [citando a wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/NO-DO)

> un noticiero semanal del régimen dictatorial franquista que se proyectaba obligatoriamente en los cines españoles antes de la película en sí, entre 1942 y 1976, y ya de forma voluntaria, hasta 1981.

que se creó, citando de nuevo a la misma fuente

> por acuerdo de la Vicesecretaría de Educación Popular del gobierno [...] «con el fin de mantener, con impulso propio y directriz adecuada, la información cinematográfica nacional»

La parte más relevante de este artículo para para esta pregunta sería la referencia a que

> El régimen franquista se sirvió del NO-DO para presentar una visión peculiar de España y del resto del mundo, con escasas posibilidades de contraste por parte de los espectadores; la prensa y la radio estaban censuradas y controladas. [...] Durante su existencia mantuvo la exclusividad en cuanto a los reportajes exhibidos en salas cinematográficas.

Por lo que se da a entender que más que presentar información para que el público la consuma y saque sus propias conclusiones, se daba esa "directriz adecuada" que tenía "escasas posibilidades de contraste por parte de los espectadores". En otras palabras, se daba información de una manera muy básica y se marcaba una línea clara de pensamiento.

Entiendo que de ahí la expresión "no te enteras ni del No-Do"  significase "no te enteras ni de algo muy claro y básico".

Mi pregunta es si, dado que la expresión parece estar estrechamente relacionada con la historia reciente de España en particular<sup>1</sup>, ¿se entiende o se usa en Hispanoamérica la expresión "no enterarse ni del nodo"?

---

<sup>1: A menos que yo esté equivocado sobre el origen de esta expresión.</sup>

Comment: En mi modesta opinión, "no te enteras ni del Nodo" se refiere a que lo ponían antes de que comenzará la película. No por su contenido.

Comment: @roetnig interesante, nunca se me había ocurrido eso. Lo mismo tengo que plantar una nueva pregunta acerca del origen de esta expresión.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @roetnig. Creo que esta expresión está emparentada con *no te enteras de la película*. En este caso, la persona a que se alude no se ha enterado ni siquiera de lo que viene antes de la película.

Comment: O "no te enteras de la misa la media"

Comment: No se entiende en Colombia. Tal vez se entendería por el contexto pero nunca lo usamos y jamás lo he oído.

Answer (score 4):

En Ecuador no se utiliza esa frase. Un ecuatoriano no la entendería y estoy seguro de que tampoco en muchos otros países de Sudamérica.

Comment: Dudo que se entienda fuera de España, e incluso en España la gente más joven tampoco lo entendería porque el NODO hace muchos años que dejó de ser obligatorio en los cines y dejó de producirse.

Answer (score 2):

Yo creo que sí se entendería, por el contexto de la frase.

Es decir, la frase comienza por "no enterarse ni de". Cualquier cosa que venga después sería deducible como algo que no se es capaz de conocer, incluso si inventáramos una palabra la frase completa nos llevaría a deducir su significado...

"No enterarse ni del *cópito*", aunque **cópito** no exista, podemos intuir el contenido o significado de la frase... Los hispanoamericanos también pensamos, como el resto de los mortales.

Comment: Vamos, que se entendería, aunque no se usa, y posiblemente nadie podría explicar el significado.