# ¿Por qué decimos que alguien “no se entera ni del nodo” para decir que no se entera de (casi) nada?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, historia, coloquialismos, españa

En [¿Se entiende en Hispanoamérica la expresión “no enterarse ni del nodo”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/27507/5481) expliqué lo que era el No-Do

> De No-Do®, marca registrada, acrónimo de *Noticiarios y Documentales*
>
> En las salas de cine de España entre 1943 y 1981, cortometraje documental que se exhibía antes de la proyección de las películas.

y elaboraba un poco cómo pensaba yo que había llegado la expresión a tener tal significado.

Incluí una breve nota al pie de la pregunta, para explicar que tal origen era mera elucubración mía, sin contrastar con ninguna fuente, y no me sorprendió que en los comentarios otro usuario propusiera una teoría alternativa:

> En mi modesta opinión, "no te enteras ni del Nodo" se refiere a que **lo ponían antes de que comenzará la película**. No por su contenido. – roetnig

¿Puede alguien sacarnos de dudas sobre el asunto? ¿Está recogido en algún sitio cómo la expresión llegó a tener ese sentido?

*Pregunta adicional (*no merece la pena hacer una tercera pregunta relacionada con esto): tal y como ha evolucionado la expresión, debería escribirla como

> No enterarse ni del **nodo**

o como

> No enterarse ni del *No-Do*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El DLE recoge la palabra como *[nodo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QZ2HrGw)*, así en minúscula ya como sustantivo común, aunque su origen sean las siglas NO-DO. Por tanto entiendo que hoy día la expresión sería "no enterarse ni del nodo", aunque en sus orígenes se escribiera así:

> *Y claro, alcalde de mis carnes, si el Concejal de Limpieza no se entera ni del N O D O, usted, querido y respetado mío, debía poner un poco, ya digo, solo un poco de interés [...].*
>
> La Provincia (Las Palmas de Gran Canaria). 18/1/1989, página 40.

Y sí, digo "sus orígenes" porque esta cita es la más antigua que he encontrado escrita de la expresión (que, por supuesto, será algo anterior, aunque diría que no mucho). Resulta curioso que la expresión se creara cuando el nodo ya había desaparecido (lo hizo definitivamente en 1981), pero parece que así fue.

Entiendo que su origen puede tener que ver con varios factores:

- El nodo se proyectaba de forma obligatoria antes de las películas emitidas en las salas de cine españolas.
- Tenía un formato semanal, por lo que si ibas varias veces al cine en la misma semana te tragabas el mismo nodo esas mismas veces.

Así pues, podía ser posible que durante la película te quedaras dormido si te aburría o que en algún momento te perdieras con la historia y dejaras de entenderla, o lo que fuera. Pero era difícil llegar a cualquiera de estos puntos durante la emisión del nodo, que tenía un formato breve, simple, y estaba hecho para llegar a la mayor cantidad de gente posible.

No encuentro casos ni en el CORDE ni en el CREA, así que poco más puedo aportar, aunque creo que no tiene más misterio que este.

Comment: Resumiendo, que no es por una sola cosa, sino posiblemente por la combinación de las tres: era corto, directo y lo ponían al principio de la proyección. Gran respuesta y gran labor de investigación.